# phpexcel Multi page print is not working

Tags: excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea('A1:R31');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea('A32:R46');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea('A47:R60');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea('A61:R75');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea('A76:R88');
```

I want to print a total of 5 pages like the code above, but it does not seem to work.

[It does not seem to work.(Image Link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf2fj.png)

[The output shape I want. (Image Link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2SVF.png)

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPrintArea('A1:R31,A32:R46,A47:R60,A61:R75,A76:R88');
```

or

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPrintArea('A1:R31', 1, PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::SETPRINTRANGE_INSERT);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPrintArea('A32:R46', 2, PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::SETPRINTRANGE_INSERT);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPrintArea('A47:R60', 3, PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::SETPRINTRANGE_INSERT);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPrintArea('A61:R75', 4, PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::SETPRINTRANGE_INSERT);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPrintArea('A76:R88', 5, PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::SETPRINTRANGE_INSERT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Thanks to that, I was able to solve it.

Comment: It seemed to be resolved, but it was not resolved.
Please refer to the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215871/phpexcel-multi-page-print-is-not-working-ask-again